Which is the subject of "being a ceaseless explorer"?

"The solo guitar format will always be indebted to SBJ* for being a ceaseless explorer and forming a legacy that will hopefully touch the hearts and minds of future generations of aspiring guitarists and musicians."

Which is the subjective noun of that phrase, "The solo guitar format" or "SBJ"?
*SBJ is Steffen Basho-Junghans, a German guitarist.

It's analogous to "Space exploration is indebted to Laika for being a good girl."

This is a good example to illustrate this question.

The preposition phrase for being a ceaseless explorer refers to SBJ.  It can’t be referring to the other one.  This is obvious as The solo guitar format is a format and can't be referred to as a ceaseless explorer.

I think I got it thanks to your help. So, it concisely says "The solo guitar format" benefited from SBJ's constant exploring and a precious musical heritage, right?

“The solo guitar format" benefited from SBJ's constant exploring and forming a precious musical heritage ...

In the expression indebted to A for B , A is always the person you are grateful to and B is the helpful thing they have done or given. You owe A a debt of gratitude.
